# In TypeScript, how do I change the value of a global variable locally?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
public login(username: string, password: string): string {

const options = {}; 
let flag = 1;  
this.auth0.client.login({realm: 'Username-Password-Authentication', username, password}, (err,authResult) => {
  if(err) {
    flag = 1;
    console.log(err);   
    return;
  }
  else if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    let flag = 0;
    this.setSession(authResult);
    alert("Flag: " + flag);
  }
  else {  
    console.log(err); 
    return;
    //alert('Error: ${err.error_description}. Check the console for further details.'); console.log(username,password)
}
});
if(flag == 0) {
  alert(flag);
  return "Invalid credentials";
}
}
```

In this code block the "if(flag == 0)" statement is never executed, since the global value is 1. How do I change the global value of flag?

Comment: "*`if(flag != 0)` statement is never executed, since the global value is 1*" doesn't make sense; `1 !== 0`.

Comment: 1) Change `flag != 0` to `flag !== 0`.  And then that statement should always fire as flag is set to 1.  2) `flag` never gets changed when that section of code fires because of the async nature of the login method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that:

```
this.auth0.client.login()
```

is asynchronous. That's why you are passing it a callback function.

What this means is that the order of operations is:

1. `let flag = 1`;
2. start the async operation with `this.auth0.client.login()`
3. test `if (flag == 0)` // which of course doesn't fire because `flag` still equals 1
4. async callbacks fire and you try to set flag, but it's too late.

You need to somehow move the logic into the async side of things. This might require that your main `login()` accepts a callback that you can fire when `is.auth0.client.login()` is done or use a promise.

One way or another your `if(flag == 0) {}` test needs to be inside the callback. And you probably don't want to create a new local variable inside the `else if` -- I think you want `flag = 0;` not `let flag = 0;`